# Find nearest parent Vue component of template ref (Vue 3)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

When a Vue [template ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html) is mounted, I want to get the nearest parent Vue component. This should be generic and work for any template ref so I've put it in a composition function (but that's just an implementation detail).

I had this working but my implementation used `elem.__vueParentComponent` while iteratively searching an element's ancestors. While reading the Vue [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/540e26f49c09edf09b6a60ac2a978fdec52686bf/packages/runtime-core/src/renderer.ts#L792) I saw `__vueParentComponent` was only enabled for dev mode or if dev tools is enabled in production. Thus, I don't want to rely on that flag being enabled.

I thought this might be possible using vnodes but this isn't easily google-able. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```js
function useNearestParentInstance(templateRef) {

  function getNearestParentInstance(el) {
    // code here
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    const el = templateRef.value;
    const instance = getNearestParentInstance(el);
    // do something with instance
  });
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <SomeComponent>
      <div>
        <div ref="myElem"></div>
      </div>
    </SomeComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    const myElem = ref();
    // nearest would be SomeComponent's instance in this case
    useNearestParentInstance(myElem);
    ...
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: In this case it's not really needed to use it that way, Because you can use a ref on the SomeComponent itself.

Comment: Yeah I understand I can add an additional ref, but this is something meant to be used in a generic way and the ideal implementation should not require the user of this function to create a ref for the parent component.

Comment: The use case for this would be difficult to explain. We're integrating Vue with a legacy framework and I'm attempting to make a seamless integration. Calling `useNearestParentInstance` with the template ref would make sense to the user of my lib but specifying the parent would not (and the parent may change if the template changes causing a defect).

Comment: so you need the nearest VueParentInstance right? thats the reason why the div parent isnt a valid parentInstance

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I need to access properties on the nearest Vue instance.

Comment: You can probably use [getCurrentInstance](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance) and call `.parent` from it, it appears

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That was my my thought as well. However, Vue getCurrentInstance() returns the root component of the .vue file. The composition function's onMounted() is executed in the context of the main vue component (not the template ref).

Comment: As a workaround, I can use a Vue component instead of a template ref and then of course I have access to this component and its parents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the nearest vue parent you can simply use

```
ref().$parent // Not sure if syntax is same in vue3
```

`ref().$parent` will get the first vuecomponent that is the parent of the ref that you placed.

Comment: $parent will returrn undefined as the template ref may not be pointing to a vue instance. In this case it's a simple div element.

Comment: $parent should target the nearest Vueparent not the first HTMLelement parent it sees.